# replace Foreach -> For

Tags: javascript, for-loop, drawimage

my program displays images using `forEach`. I want to replace it with `for`

```
  images.forEach((img, ind) =>  {
    const oImage = new Image();
        oImage.onload = () => 
        {
          ctx.drawImage(oImage, ind * 100, 0, 100, 100);
        };
    oImage.src = img.textContent;
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: to better understand the "forEach" function
I did not understand well

Comment: @stargatesg1 I recommend you to study the use of forEach since it could be more easier to use than a traditional for. See the different ways [you can iterate over an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/7927192)

Comment: There is no actual question in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to get rid of forEach, but you have the answer and it's simple as this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  const oImage = new Image();
  oImage.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(oImage, i * 100, 0, 100, 100);
  };

  oImage.src = images[i].textContent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,
I understand better "forEach", I could not do it with "For"